# Slice pandas dataframe into equal lengths of 34

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the below:

```
    page    hour    count
0   3899549 399593  1530
1   3899549 399594  1610
2   3899549 399595  1592
3   3899549 399596  1220
4   3899549 399597  1729
5   3899549 399598  224
6   3899549 399599  481
```

The full data set is available here:
http://www.sharecsv.com/s/b2dbe8e49d6a2481de138f6ca06c679e/test.csv

For each page, there is 34 hours worth of consecutive hour data.  There are some instances where the same pages has 34 hours worth of data over multiple different time periods.  This is problematic, as when I create a groupby dataframe, I get groups that are multiples larger than 34.  Ideally, I would like to slice each of these groups into a max of 34 hours.  This should be made easier by the fact that the hour data is consecutive. In the linked data set the page 0f `3694750` is an example of a page that has multiple 34 hour periods.

Ideally, for the pages that have multiple groups of 34, i'd like to add a suffix of _1, _2, _3, etc. so I can groupby for all specific instances of a page.  I would need it like this because i need to pivot the data.

I tried the below with no success:

```
for name, group in hourly_groups:
        for i, x in enumerate(group):
            print x
```

And

```
for k, g in df_hourly.groupby(df_hourly['page'] - 34):
    print g
```

Comment: Do you want 34 sized groups of hours that span pages, or you want for each page, the data split in equal 34 hour chunks?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid For each page, data split into 34 hour chunks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your description is still confusing.

It's a little tricky to get it all right

```
import pandas as pd


cols = ['instance', 'page', 'hour', 'count']
data = [
    (0, 3899549, 399593, 1530),
    (1, 3899549, 399594, 1610),
    (2, 3899549, 399595, 1592),
    (3, 3899549, 399596, 1220),
    (4, 3899549, 399597, 1729),
    (0, 3694750, 395862, 0),
    (1, 3694750, 395863, 0),
    (2, 3694750, 395864, 0),
    (3, 3694750, 395865, 0),
    (4, 3694750, 395866, 0),
    (0, 3694750, 395862, 1),
    (1, 3694750, 395863, 1),
    (2, 3694750, 395864, 1),
    (3, 3694750, 395865, 1),
    (4, 3694750, 395866, 1),
]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=cols)
grouped = df.groupby(['page', 'instance'])


def g(group):
    group.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    group['page'] = group.apply(f, axis=1)
    return group


def f(row):
    if row.name > 0:
        return str(row.page) + '_{0}'.format(int(row.name))
    else:
        return row.page

res = grouped.apply(g)
res.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print res.sort('page')
```

example output:

```
instance       page    hour  count
6          3    3694750  395865      0
0          0    3694750  395862      0
2          1    3694750  395863      0
8          4    3694750  395866      0
4          2    3694750  395864      0
14         4    3899549  399597   1729
10         0    3899549  399593   1530
11         1    3899549  399594   1610
12         2    3899549  399595   1592
13         3    3899549  399596   1220
1          0  3694750_1  395862      1
5          2  3694750_1  395864      1
7          3  3694750_1  395865      1
3          1  3694750_1  395863      1
9          4  3694750_1  395866      1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.arange(len(df)//34)` to do the trick.

```
df = pd.read_csv('/home/Jian/Downloads/test.csv', index_col=[0])
grouped = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//34)

# sample group
grouped.get_group(1)

       page    hour  count
0   3694750  395862      0
1   3694750  395863      0
2   3694750  395864      0
3   3694750  395865      0
4   3694750  395866      0
5   3694750  395867      0
6   3694750  395868      0
7   3694750  395869      0
..      ...     ...    ...
26  3694750  395888   1215
27  3694750  395889    876
28  3694750  395890    726
29  3694750  395891    496
30  3694750  395892    908
31  3694750  395893   1362
32  3694750  395894   1732
33  3694750  395895   1968

[34 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I added an edit - is there any way you can fit this into your answer? `Ideally, for the pages that have multiple groups of 34, i'd like to add a suffix of _1, _2, _3, etc. so I can groupby for all specific instances of a page.  I would need it like this because i need to pivot the data.`